# It's possible to create another organization or create sub-organization in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I have a problem when create organization in GCP. I have a secondary domain and want to use it to set an organization in GCP but I can't see how to get it. So, It's possible to create another organization or create sub-organization?

Comment: You can create 1 organisation per domain. So yes, create another organization based on your second domain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. There is no sub-organizations in GCP [Resources hierarchy](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/cloud-platform-resource-hierarchy).
2. Yes, you can create another organization by creating a Google Workspace (formerly G-Suite) or Cloud Identity account and associate it with a domain.

---

As quoted from [docs](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-organization):

> Once you have created your Google Workspace or Cloud Identity account
> and associated it with a domain, your organization resource will be
> automatically created for you. The resource will be provisioned at
> different times depending on your account status:
>
> - If you are new to Google Cloud and have not created a project yet, the organization resource will be created for you when you log in to the Google Cloud console and accept the terms and conditions.
> - If you are an existing Google Cloud user, the organization resource    will be created for you when you create a new project or billing account. Any projects you created previously will be listed under "No organization", and this is normal. The organization resource will appear and the new project you created will be linked to it automatically.
> - You will need to move any projects you created under "No organization" into your new organization resource. For instructions on how to move your projects, see Migrating projects into an organization.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can I have some question plz. I try to use secondary domain to set new cloud identity but It said "This domain is already used". I'm set secondary domain in Admin Console. So, This can be reason that google said error like that?

Comment: @cusniwtt Well, this could be due to multiple reasons! if you have already associated your domain with another google account, you will have to remove this association and wait up to 24 hours then associate it with the correct account. See [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/80610#zippy=%2Cthis-domain-is-already-in-use) for a full list of what might cause this error and how to fix that.